# Translating text of a parent template block in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

How can i translate the entire block in the parent template `page.html.twig`:

```
{# app/Resources/views/page.html.twig #}
{% extends '::bootstrap.html.twig' %}

{% block page %}
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>{% block header %}{% endblock %} 
        <small>{% block small %}{% endblock %}</small></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

... instead of calling `trans` in each child template?

```
{# src/AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/views/User/show.html.twig #}
{% extends '::page.html.twig' %}

{% block header %}{% trans %}Utente{% endtrans %}{% endblock %}
{% block small %}{% trans %}dettaglio{% endtrans %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

I've tried surround `{% block header %}` with `{% trans %}` but it complains about `trans` that should be a simple string and not an expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind. Found it by myself using `block` directly:

```
{% block page %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>{{ block('header')|trans }} 
    <small>{{ block('small')|trans }}</small></h1>
</div>
<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not going to delete the question since i can't find any similar...

Comment: Awesome. I couldn't find the answer too!

Comment: @Sydney_o9 glad to be of help. The only bad occurs when (say) `small` contains a dynamic string. I'm looking for a better solution than leaving `{% block small %}{% endblock %}`...